# Wrong annotation: class_id = 1. But class_id should be [from 0 to 0], file: data/obj/20210221_112744.txt

Tags: python, yolo

I am using Yolo to train custom object detection while training i am getting following error

```
   Wrong annotation: class_id = 1. But class_id should be [from 0 to 0], file: data/obj/20210221_112732.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a review of the YOLO label format:

```
<class id> <Xo/X> <Yo/Y> <W/X> <H/Y>
```

Where:

`<class id>`, label index of the class, integer object number from 0 to (classes-1)

`<Xo/X>` coordinate of the bounding box’s center

`<Yo/Y>` coordinate of the bounding box’s center

`W,` Width of the bounding box

`H,` Height of the bounding box

`X,` Width of the image

`Y,` Height of the image

It seems like you have put `classes=1` in your `data` file. That means your `class id` should be `0` in the labels. Edit the `class id` in your labels to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you have 1 class so the class id become 0. if you have more than 1 classes, the class id should be 0 to 1. the solution, you can add this:

classes = 2 in cfg, .data, and .names file, so you must change the filters, steps, max_batches in cfg files

it works for me